# not all arguments converted during string formatting?

Tags: python, generator

```
print(*(i for index, i in enumerate(list(input(int()).split())) if i % 6 == 0 and (index+1) % 6 == 0), sep=' '`)
```

You can see my code but the matter is the error below:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What should I do?

```
input:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

output:
6 12
```

Comment: This isn't very pythonic IMO, cramming all of those operations into one line. You're becoming a victim of that approach because it becomes increasingly harder to debug.

Comment: Is this your full code? When I run this I just get `0` printed

Comment: `int()` is just `0`; `.split()` returns a list so no need to wrap in `list()`

Comment: @karl post edited

Comment: @Chris_Rands post edited

Comment: `print(*(x for i, x in enumerate(input().split(), 1) if i % 6 == int(x) % 6 == 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is a string. You need to convert it to int before the `%` operation

```
print(*(i for index, i in enumerate(list(input(int()).split())) if int(i) % 6 == 0 and index % 6 == 0), sep=' ')
```

Also, the expected output you posted above is wrong - in this case `index = int(i) - 1` (when `i == 1`, `index == 0`) - so both `i` and `index` being multiples of `6` is not possible

Comment: you were write but one more thing is that if i want to check if I want not to print a number twice ?? what should i do ?

Comment: Use `set` instead of a `generator`. Simply replace the `()` with a `{}` -----

`print(*{i for index, i in enumerate(list(input(int()).split())) if int(i) % 6 == 0}, sep=' ') `

Comment: You can use the built-in `sorted` function to sort a set - note that it will return a list